# How to tell the address of the smtp server on my local Ubuntu OS?

Tags: ubuntu, smtp

I have tested and it seems I do have an `SMTP` server running locally.

What I don't know is how to get its `URL` and login credentials.

Any idea how to find those?

Comment: That'll likely depend on which smtp server it is. Can you telnet to localhost port 25 and post the greeting so we (hopefully!) know which one you're running?

Comment: I've never heard of an SMTP server having a URL. They almost always run on TCP port 25. What's your end goal here?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a standard Ubuntu then you have a Postfix running on it. And there is no user authentication for it. In the default configuration it is only allowed to send mail to local users (not to users elsewhere on the Internet).
You can send mails to any user on your box by just using `username@hostname`. The server to use is just `localhost`.